# Homogenize grouped values in R in panel dataset

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, panel-data

I have a household panel survey dataset. It has two surveys in it: one for individuals and one for households. One person in each household answers both while all other people in the household answer the individual survey only. The municipal location is only in the person who filled the houehold. The dataset is a panel so each observation is there multiple times for different waves of the study. So basically I have something like this:

```
  df <- data.frame(id = c (11,11, 12,12,13, 13,14, 14,21, 21,22, 22,31, 31,32, 32,33, 33,34, 34,41, 41,42, 42,43, 43,44, 44,51, 51,61, 61,62, 62))
df$idhousehold <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, 5,5, 6, 6, 6,6)
df$municipality <- c(NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA,"A","A",NA, NA, "A", "A",NA, NA,NA, NA, "B", "B", NA,NA, "A", "A",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, "C", "C","B","B",NA, NA)
df$year <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
df
```

What I basically want to do is to assign the same municipality value for everyone within the same household. In the example above this means everyone in households 1, 2 and 4 has value "A" for municipality, for households 3 and 6 everyone has B and C in 5. I cannot manually do that because the dataset has around 130k observations.

I tried multiple ways of goruping the data and mutating a new variable but I am not capable of getting what I want.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using the `fill()` function from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id = c (11,11, 12,12,13, 13,14, 14,21, 21,22, 22,31, 31,32, 32,33, 33,34, 34,41, 41,42, 42,43, 43,44, 44,51, 51,61, 61,62, 62))
df$idhousehold <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, 5,5, 6, 6, 6,6)
df$municipality <- c(NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA,"A","A",NA, NA, "A", "A",NA, NA,NA, NA, "B", "B", NA,NA, "A", "A",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, "C", "C","B","B",NA, NA)
df$year <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(idhousehold) %>% 
  fill(municipality, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  ungroup()

df
#> # A tibble: 34 x 4
#>       id idhousehold municipality  year
#>    <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1    11           1 A                1
#>  2    11           1 A                2
#>  3    12           1 A                1
#>  4    12           1 A                2
#>  5    13           1 A                1
#>  6    13           1 A                2
#>  7    14           1 A                1
#>  8    14           1 A                2
#>  9    21           2 A                1
#> 10    21           2 A                2
#> # … with 24 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As there is only a single value per household, you can do:

```
df$municipality <- ave(df$municipality, df$idhousehold, FUN = na.omit)
```

However, as there seem to be missing values in the data and cases where there are multiple municipality values per household you can do:

```
df$municipality <- ave(df$municipality, df$idhousehold, FUN = function(x) unique(na.omit(x))[1])

df
   id idhousehold municipality
1  11           1            A
2  12           1            A
3  13           1            A
4  14           1            A
5  21           2            A
6  22           2            A
7  31           3            B
8  32           3            B
9  33           3            B
10 34           3            B
11 41           4            A
12 42           4            A
13 43           4            A
14 44           4            A
15 51           5            C
16 61           6            B
17 62           6            B
```

Equivalent with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(idhousehold) %>%
  mutate(municipality = unique(na.omit(municipality))[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But it wouldn't do it: the first solution yield "Error: Column `municipality` must be length 5 (the group size) or one, not 2"
and the second one: "Error in x[i] <- value[[j]] : replacement has length zero"

Comment: You have both cases where there is more than one municipality value by id and cases where there are none.

Comment: Have edited my answer but it would be better to see a sample of your real data.  As you have multiple municipality values per household you should check that they are not multiple distinct values.  Also check that the `NA` values are actually `NA` and not a character or factor value masquerading as `NA`.

Comment: Sorry, this is a panel dataset, so each observation is there for multiple waves/years. I updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(municipality=case_when(idhousehold %in% c(1,2,4)~ "A",idhousehold %in% c(3,6) ~ "B",idhousehold %in% 5 ~"C"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that would do it but I have over 130k observations and hundreds of values for household so it would take me forever to do it and I would probably make some mistakes in it.